# ¿Qué devuelve "if(s.compareTo(cuentas.get(i).obtenerCuenta())==0)"

Tags: java

Estoy en este código

```
public boolean eliminar (String s){
        for (int i = 0; i < cuentas.size(); i++) {
            if(s.compareTo(cuentas.get(i).obtenerCuenta())==0){
                cuentas.remove(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

pero en esta instrucción no logro entender ***qué*** ni ***cómo*** devuelve
el *true* o el *false*

```
s.compareTo(cuentas.get(i).obtenerCuenta())==0
```

¿cómo funciona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `s.compareTo(cuentas.get(i).obtenerCuenta())==0` **¿cómo funciona?**
>
> `s` es una cadena
>
> `cuentas` es una lista
>
> `cuentas.get(i)` obtienes un  elemento de la lista de cuentas
>
> `cuentas.get(i).obtenerCuenta()` obtienes la cuenta del elemento

entonces `s`  es comparado con la cuenta del elemento

la funcion compareTo revisar: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm

La parte que nos interesa es el retorno de la funcion `compareTo`

> Valor de retorno El valor 0 si el parametro es igual a esta cadena; un
>   valor inferior a 0 si el parametro es mayor que esta cadena; y un
>   valor mayor que 0 es si el parametro es menor de esta cadena.

Entonces:

si es igual a `0` quiere decir que `s` es igual a la **cuenta del elemento**

Answer (score 1):

El método compareTo de la clase String sirve para comparar cadenas, este método está definido en la interfaz `Comparable`, el valor de la comparación es de tipo `int`, que determina la distancia de diferencia entre dos cadenas dependiendo de los caracteres que la componen, si la distancia es cero entonces asumes que el valor es igual

Por lo tanto estás comparando la variable `s` con cada cuenta de la lista, si son iguales la elimina de la lista.

Adicionalmente, la interfaz `Comparable` es más usada para realizar ordenamiento de arrays, si quieres comparar igualdad es mejor usar el método `.equals` que retorna un valor de tipo `Boolean` (`true` o `false`), este método está definido en la clase `Object` pero la clase `String` la sobreescribe para comparar la igualdad del contenido de las cadenas.

```
if (s.equals(cuentas.get(i).obtenerCuenta())
```

Además debes tomar en cuenta que al comparar una cadena con valores nulos, el comportamiento no es similar.

Con el método `equals` si la cuenta tiene valor nulo el resultado será `false`, en cambio utilizando el método `.compareTo` para comparar con un valor nulo Java te lanzará una campaña excepción `NullPointerException` en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: En Java, los arreglos no tienen un método `get`, pero las [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) sí.